# Replace Files in Git Repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a working app in a git repository on gitlab. To track down a bug, I rebuilt the app, feature by feature, in a new application directory. The bug is gone and now I want to update the files in the repository with the files from the new application directory. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directory

1.Create new git repository:

```
git init
```

2.Add your remote repository to the upstreams:

```
git remote add origin git@.......
```

-your repository git address

3.Checkout the branch your remote repository uses:

```
git checkout -b master (or any other branch that holds your code)
```

4.Add and commit your changes:

```
git add dir/file.py (or php or whatever)

git commit -m 'bug fixed'
```

4.Pull the remote changes:

```
git pull origin master   (or whatever other branch is used)
```

5.Push your changes to the remote origin:

```
git push origin master   (or any other branch you checked out)
```

At that point your code should be at the repository

Comment: When I run `git checkout master` I get the error, "pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.", even though gitlab appears to show that the current path is named "master".

Comment: git checkout -b master                                                                                should fix it as you're creating a new branch master. You can run git status and see that you're indeed on master. If the branch you're pulling from has different name you can get there same way git checkout branchname